# How find this matrix determinant value

Tags: determinant

Find the value 
$$
\det\left|
\begin{array}{c&c&c&c&c}
  0 &  1   &  1   &  1   &  1   \\
  1 &  0   & AB^2 & AC^2 & AP^2 \\
  1 & AB^2 &  0   & BC^2 & BP^2 \\
  1 & AC^2 & BC^2 &  0   & CP^2 \\
  1 & AP^2 & BP^2 & CP^2 & 0
\end{array}
\right|\,.
$$
where 
$$AB=a,AC=c,AP=8,BC=\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2},BP=8,CP=6$$
when I deal a math problem, and I feel very ugly by hand, can you someone can use computer to help me find this determinant? Thank you

Comment: Try $R_i\rightarrow R_i-R_2$ for $i=3,4,5$. May be that can help

Comment: Have you tried using Wolfram Alpha yourself?

Comment: @user7530,I can't use Wolfram Alpha to find the determinant. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find the determinant by computer rather than by hand, but finding the determinant manually is actually not that difficult. By permutation, the determinant is equal to
\begin{align}
&\left|\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
0&a^2&c^2&8^2&1\\
a^2&0&a^2-ac+c^2&8^2&1\\
c^2&a^2-ac+c^2&0&6^2&1\\
\hline
8^2&8^2&6^2&0&1\\
1&1&1&1&0
\end{array}\right|\\
=&
\left|\begin{array}{c|c}
X&Y\\ \hline Y^T&Z
\end{array}\right|
=\det(Z)\det(X-YZ^{-1}Y^T)\\
=&
-\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0&a^2&c^2\\
a^2&0&a^2-ac+c^2\\
c^2&a^2-ac+c^2&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
8^2&1\\
8^2&1\\
6^2&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
8^2&8^2&6^2\\
1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\right)\\
=&
-\det\begin{bmatrix}
-128&a^2-128&c^2-100\\
a^2-128&-128&a^2-ac+c^2-100\\
c^2-100&a^2-ac+c^2-100&-72\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
So, you only need to evaluate the determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a computer-generated answer, [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20of%20%7B%7B0%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%200%2C%20a%5E2%2C%20c%5E2%2C%208%5E2%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%20a%5E2%2C%200%2C%20a%5E2-a%20c%20%2B%20c%5E2%2C%208%5E2%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%20c%5E2%2C%20a%5E2-a%20c%2B%20c%5E2%2C%200%2C%206%5E2%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%208%5E2%2C%208%5E2%2C%206%5E2%2C%200%7D%7D)'s one from Wolfram Alpha. Looks like it's not surprising your hand calculations became a mess.

By the way, it's worth taking the time to learn simple Mathematica syntax so that you can use Wolfram Alpha, which is a great, free tool for simple quick & dirty symbolic computations.